# How do I create a FaceRecognizer from a pointer in OpenCV for Android

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface

I am using OpenCV 2.4.10.

JNI - Train the facialRecognition

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_sample_facialRecognition_DetectionBasedRecognition_nativeTrain
(JNIEnv * jenv, jstring pathIn)
{
    vector<Mat> images;
    vector<int> labels;
    try {

        std::string path;
        std::string classlabel = "A";
        GetJStringContent(jenv,pathIn,path);

        if(!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty()) {
            images.push_back(imread(path, 0));
            labels.push_back(atoi(classlabel.c_str()));
        }
        Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
        model->train(images, labels);

        model.addref(); //don't let it self-destroy here..
        FaceRecognizer * pf = model.obj;
        return (jlong) pf;

    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Java - train the recognizer

```
mNativeRecognition = nativeTrain(getFilesDir().toString());
```

Java - do the detection and recognition

```
nativeDetect(mGray, faces, mNativeRecognition);
```

JNI - recognize

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_sample_facialRecognition_DetectionBasedTracker_nativeDetect
(JNIEnv * jenv, jclass, jlong thiz, jlong imageGray, jlong faces, jlong recog)
{
    jint whoAreYou= 0;

    try
    {
        vector<Rect> RectFaces;
        ((DetectionBasedTracker*)thiz)->process(*((Mat*)imageGray));
        ((DetectionBasedTracker*)thiz)->getObjects(RectFaces);

        Ptr < FaceRecognizer > model = recog; //here is the problem

        vector_Rect_to_Mat(RectFaces, *((Mat*)faces));

        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            cv::Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
            cv::Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);

            cv::Rect face_i = faces[i];

            cv::Mat face = grayscaleFrame(face_i);
            cv::Mat face_resized;

            cv::resize(face, face_resized, cv::Size(100, 120), 1.0, 1.0, INTER_CUBIC);
            whoAreYou = model->predict(face_resized);
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {

        //catch...
    }

    return whoAreYou;
}
```

So I am trying to convert the stored pointer from nativeTrain, and use it real time to detect and recognize a face in one function.  How do I convert that pointer back into a useable FaceRecognizer in nativeDetect?

Comment: try: `FaceRecognizer * model = (FaceRecognizer *)recog; //here is the problem`. if you use the cv::Ptr version, should be: `Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model( (FaceRecognizer *)recog);` and ` model.addref();` at the end of the func.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: As in berak's comment, it is better to go with raw pointer version or else you will need to save the object with `addref`.

If still preferring the `cv::Ptr` version, instead of `Ptr < FaceRecognizer > model = recog;`, we should give

```
Ptr < FaceRecognizer > model( (FaceRecognizer *)recog );
model->addref();
```

Smart pointer implementations in C++ ( `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` or deprecated `std::auto_ptr` ) , will not support an *assignment* from raw pointer to smart pointer. See old `cv::Ptr` implementation here([1](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.10.x-prep/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp#L1282)). They also add an `explicit` keyword([2](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0-ocl-tp2/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp#L216)) to prevent accidental conversions from raw pointers to smart pointers.

Note: In OpenCV 3.0, `Ptr` class, `obj` member is private([3](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0-ocl-tp2/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp#L292)) and `addref` method is removed. So this won't work with 3.0. Also curios why all these invocation over JNI. No Java wrappers ?

Comment: "No Java wrappers ? " unfortunately, not in this case. the java api is script -generated, and this script does not know, how to handle cv::Ptr properly.

Comment: @berak [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) generates wrappers for that: [public static FaceRecognizer createEigenFaceRecognizer()](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_contrib.html#createEigenFaceRecognizer--)